# Difference between "of the reasons why" and "why"

Tags: word-choice

Is there any difference between "of the reasons why" and "why"?

Which of the following is better in formal speeches?

- Could you inform us why...
- Could you inform us of the reasons why...

According to the Oxford Dictionary, why means "For what reason or purpose". Hence, isn't "of the reasons why" repetitive?

Comment: Largely, but it's not incorrect, and does prompt for _all_ the reasons.

Comment: As you said the second one sounds repetitive, but at the end of the day I guess it sounds more formal, indeed...